# Why is the object not defined in the JavaScript console's opinion in the rendering function? (three.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is the code, and it's running in my browser. It seems that the object with the texture is rendered properly, but JavaScript console writes that *mycylinder* is not defined. Why? How can I resolve this problem?

```
var texture,material,mycylinder;
var WIDTH = 400, HEIGHT = 300;
var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT =WIDTH/HEIGHT, NEAR=0.1, FAR =10000;

var renderer= new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
var camera= new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, NEAR, FAR);
var scene= new THREE.Scene();

scene.add(camera);
camera.position.set(0,150,400);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
light.position.set(0,250,0);
scene.add(light);

var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x444444);
scene.add(ambientLight);

var cylinderLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
cylinderLoader.load( "models/probahenger.js", addModel );

function addModel( geometry, materials ) {

            texture= new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/Henger_anyag3.png");
            material= new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: texture});
            mycylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,material);                
            mycylinder.scale.set(30,30,30);
            mycylinder.position.y=0;
            scene.add( mycylinder );

        };

function render() {

        requestAnimationFrame(render);

        mycylinder.rotation.x += 0.01;
        mycylinder.rotation.y += 0.01;

        renderer.render(scene, camera); 
}

render();
```

Comment: If you're checking for the existence of `mycylinder` before your model has been loaded, it's going to be `undefined`. You might want to call `render` at the end of your `addModel` function. But since you're passing `render` to `requestAnimationFrame`, it keeps going and eventually finds it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the object hasn't been loaded by the time you're trying to rotate it. This should do the trick:

```
if ( mycylinder !== undefined ) {

    mycylinder.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mycylinder.rotation.y += 0.01;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) It runs well now :)